# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None) for outlook.application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, outlook

I tried all the solutions from here, but none of them worked. Please help with this error as I am trying to send form value 'message' to mail. I am using FLASK.

**pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)
for outlook.application.
can you please help**

Here is my code snippet. Sorry I cannot provide full code as it is project-specific.'

```
import os, csv
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
def send_mail(data):
if request.method=='POST':
    EMailIDs=open('C:\\Users\\PO323206\\Downloads\\python scripts\\web server\\emails.txt').read()
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)        
    mail.To = EMailIDs[0]
    mail.Cc = EMailIDs[1]
    mail.Subject = "New Message from ISP Web Page"
    mail.HTMLBody = """<html><left><b><i><font size=8 color="#cc00cc" face="Brush Script MT">Hi</i></b></font></left></html>"""
    mail.send()


@app.route('/submit_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit():
    if request.method=='POST':
        data=request.form.to_dict()
        write_to_csv(data)
        send_mail(data)
        return redirect('/thankyou.html')
```

Please let me know if any further info needed.

Thanks!

Comment: what line is the error coming from?

Comment: I get this - "pywintypes.com_error

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last)

    File "C:\Users\PO323206\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch

     [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)"